# Intent not working in android menu bar

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating an app where there is a button on the action bar called About.
It should link to an activity by the same name through intent method. But its not working.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch(item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.About:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;

    default:    
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }


 }
```

this is the java code, declaring the action to do when the user clicks on action bar button.

The XML code that creates the button is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<item android:id="@+id/About" android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="About"/>



</menu>
```

The menu button is being created and it is clickable, but no event is taking place.

The content of my android manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ted"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ted.SplashPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_page"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ted.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.ted.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" >
/



    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ted.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.ted.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.ted.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ted.DisplayMessageActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message_activity2"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.ted.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.ted.DisplayMessageActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ted.RSS"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rss"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.ted.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.ted.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ted.About"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.ted.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.ted.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you simply cannot have two Activies with the same name

Comment: which activities are you talking about?

Comment: About.class and your main activiy

Comment: can you put the content of your AndroidManifest file ?

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: When its clicked, nothing is happening

Answer (score 1):

change your menu.xml file to this
add the header

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.ted.MainActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/About"
        android:title="About"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```